# Selecting an appended anchor using .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append an anchor with the same class as an existing anchor, and then target the appended anchor using `.click()`. My current code works perfectly with the existing anchor, but it does not work with the appended anchor, even though both have the same class. How can I target the appended anchor?

Check out [this JS fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wbRR7/1/) for a better idea of what I mean.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="append">Append.</a>

<div class="div1">
    <a href="#" class="link">Link.</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.append').click(function(){
  $('.div1').append('<a href="#" class="link">Appended link</a>');
});

$("a.link").click(function(){
  alert("The link was clicked.");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need delegated event handlers for that :

```
$('.append').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchor = $('<a />', {href: '#', 'class': 'link', text: 'Appended link'});
    $('.div1').append(anchor);
})

$('.div1').on('click', 'a.link', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     alert("The link was clicked.");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wbRR7/2/)